# jQuery + localStorage - JSON value check true or false

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

We are storing a value in localstorage with Key name - `cookiesettings`. The value will be in JSON format like below.

```js
{
   "enabled":true,
   "element1":{
      "enabled":true
   },
   "element2":{
      "enabled":true
   },
   "element3":{
      "enabled":false
   }
}
```

Not sure how to extract and check whether element3 is enabled true/false. If true, we need to show div. otherwise, hide div.

tried to use

```
localStorage.getItem('cookiesetting');
localStorage.getItem('cookiesetting.element3.enabled');
```

But getting undefined error. Tried to use:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cookiesetting'));
```

Still can't able to find a solution to check whether element3 - Enabled - True or False.

Comment: After getting and parsing the value it should be an object already so just use `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cookiesetting')).element3.enabled` to get it's value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this documentation which says Key and Value must be String.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

So you have to store it a stringified version of the Object.

```
localStorage.setItem('cookiesetting', JSON.stringify({
  "enabled":true,
  "element1":{
    "enabled":true
  },
  "element2":{
    "enabled":true
  },
  "element3":{
    "enabled":false
  }
}))
```

You can get the Item by:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cookiesetting'))
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cookiesetting')).element3.enabled
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` can't store objects, You need to store the `JSON` as a string, So convert your `cookieObject` to string before storing to the `localStorage`

```
localStorage.setItem('cookiesetting', JSON.stringify(cookieItem));
```

Get the string from localStorage and parse it and use like below

```
    let cookiesetting = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cookiesetting'));
    if (!!cookiesetting) {
      console.log(cookiesetting.element3.enabled);
    }
```

```js
let cookieItem = {
  "enabled": true,
  "element1": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "element2": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "element3": {
    "enabled": false
  }
};

localStorage.setItem('cookiesetting', JSON.stringify(cookieItem));
let cookiesetting = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cookiesetting'));
if (!!cookiesetting) {
  console.log(cookiesetting.element3.enabled);
}
```